# Security concerns for WAMP as a development environment

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I would like to install WAMP on our computers so that we can do offline Wordpress development, but the IT department has a few security concerns that I'm hoping you could help address.

1. They fear that an outside hacker could take control of the server via internet. Can this concern be addressed when the intention is only to use WAMP for local (offline) development, although the computers are connected to the internet.
2. They fear that a user can leave WAMP running in the background also when other users log in. Can WAMP stay running when the Windows user logs out? If yes, can this be prevented?

Comment: The operating system is only have the issue here. Certainly MS-Windows is a relatively insecure platform, but the bigger risk probably is wordpress. Why don't you use virtual machines for that? A predefined minimal linux based image which is maintained in a central way. Such approach offers _tons_ of advantages: every developer has the same platform, same settings, you can run automated tests, you are independent of network topology and locally installed software.

Comment: Thanks, using a virtual machine sounds like a good way to address our concerns!

Comment: ___Point 1___: An attacker would first have to break through your routers NAT firewall to gain access to you PC and the Apache on it. If they can break through that firewall, then the existance of Apache on a few PC's is **Totally Irrelevant** and in fact adds complexity to a hack

Comment: ___Point 2___ If you are worried about people sharing a PC, then again the existance of Apache running in the background is probably the least of your worries. A simple `Exit` of WAMPServer will shutdown Apache and MYSQL